# Notícias apenas para determinado grupo no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Ao inserir um post no wordpress, tenho a taxonomia 'grupo' com termos 'farmácias, mercearias, lanchonetes...', que são os grupos, pois já tenho clientes para esses grupos.
O que preciso é que, ao fazer login para ter acesso restrito na área do cliente, o wordpress verifique se tem notícia para o grupo cujo cliente faz parte e, caso haja, mostre-o juntamente com os post especificamente pro cliente.

Para mostrar notícias direcionadas para o cliente já tenho, só não estou conseguindo fazer essa verificação por grupos.

```
/*
Eu tenho o ID do CLIENTE na $_GET.
Tenho que buscar os grupos que o cliente participa
Checar se algum desses grupos tem vinculo com a noticia
*/
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key' => 'clientes',
    'value' => $_GET['id'],
    'compare' => '='
);

$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'grupo'
);

$args = array(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'noticias'
        ,'meta_query' => $meta_query
    )
);    

$tmp = new WP_Query($args);

if(!$tmp->have_posts()){
    echo 'não tem notícias no momento';
    return;
}

while ($tmp->have_posts()){
    $tmp->the_post(); 
    echo get_the_title().'<br>';
}
```

Observação: O cliente é inserido no post_type 'clientes'. Nesse post_type tenho os campos email, senha e os grupos são listados da forma de taxonomia para poder vincular o cliente ao grupo.

Comment: O login não é feito no padrão do WP. Tem um formulário específico para ele. Onde a partir desse formulário é pego o 'id' do cliente para fazer as verificações de acesso de notícia.

Comment: Flávia Amaral, você está salvando o grupo do usuário no postmeta correto?

Comment: Sim, sim Leandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não seria melhor você mudar a key para cliente_grupo e o valor dela seria o grupo pertencente do cliente, como você já está passando o id do cliente na url, pegaria assim:

**$grupo_cliente = get_post_meta( $_GET['id'], 'cliente_grupo', true );**

```
                $type = 'noticias';
            $args=array(
                'post_type' => $type,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                    'meta_key'       => 'grupo',
                                    'meta_value'     => $grupo_cliente

            );
                           $tmp = new WP_Query($args);

           if(!$tmp->have_posts()){
              echo 'não tem notícias no momento';
             return;
           }

          while ($tmp->have_posts()){
            $tmp->the_post(); 
            echo get_the_title().'<br>';
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou presumir que os usuários (clientes) ao cadastrarem/registrarem no **WordPress**, escolham o grupo do qual irão fazer parte e consequentemente isso irá salvar um novo metadado do usuário ao banco de dados.

Para recuperar essa informação que foi informada durante o cadastro, você precisará usar a função `get_user_meta` passando então a chave do metadado, digamos por exemplo que você optou por chamá-la de `user_group_info`, você então recupera o valor de `user_group_info`, realize as checagens necessárias e por fim tenta obter os posts de acordo com o valor de `user_group_info`.

- [Customizing the Registration Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)
- [add_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)
- [get_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)